# D3 Select Element by Class and Return Element Id

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My HTML looks like this:

```
<button class="leaflet-clickable" id="Abilene">Abilene</button>
<button class="leaflet-clickable" id="Augusta-Richmond County">Augusta-Richmond County</button>
<button class="leaflet-clickable" id="Honolulu">Honolulu</button>
```

And, my D3 code looks something like this (lets assume all the obvious things like referencing D3's library etc are correct):

```
d3.selectAll(".leaflet-clickable").on("click", function(){
        console.log("test");

        msa = d3.select(".leaflet-clickable").text(function(content){
            console.log(content);
            return content;
        });
        changeSubGroupData(msa);
    });
```

I am trying to capture the ID in the DOM when the button is clicked. No errors in the console and I have not found an answer to this anywhere. I have looked [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials), to see if any of the tutorials cover this specific issue to no avail. What I have above is wrong. How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully, D3 provides a reference to the selection through `this`:

```
d3.selectAll('.leaflet-clickable').on('click', function() {
    console.log(d3.select(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Try that

Comment: My fault. Nice work. Would love a thumbs up if you thought the question was relevant. Cheers. ;)